# tell user to press only +

Tags: c#, character, calculator

i am trying to ask user to press only '+' key and if user gave a wrong input tell him that is not an operation; for example if user inputs numbers or any other keys, tell user "you have to input an operation"
i have tried codes below but does not get fixed!

```
Console.WriteLine("press '+' to add\npress '-' to delete");

//these are the ways i have tried:
//1:

char add = '+';
if (Console.ReadKey() == add) ;

//2:
string input = Console.ReadLine();
char inputChar = Convert.ToChar(input); 

//if user give number the program shows error to me
if (inputChar == add) ;

//3:
if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.+) ;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try implementing `do .. while` loop:

```
  char op;

  do {
    Console.WriteLine("press '+' to add\npress '-' to delete");

    op = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
  }
  while (op != '+' && op != '-');
```

we keep asking user until valid operation (`op`) is provided (either `'+'` or `'-'`)